# How can lifecycle aware components using LifecycleObserver be aware of screen orientation changes

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Making a lifecycle aware component is super easy with `LifecycleObserver` e.g. pausing and stopping `MediaPlayer` when the user is leaving the screen.

But is there any way for me to know if the lifecycle is going through `onPause`, `onStop` etc. just because a configuration change is happening? In that case, I wouldn't do anything to the `MediaPlayer`. In `Fragment` there is `activity?.isChangingConfiguration()` but in `LifecycleObserver` I don't get such information as far as I'm aware?

```
class AudioPlayerLifecycleObserver(private val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer) : LifecycleObserver {
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE) 
    fun onPause() {
        // Media player will pause even if the screen is just changing orientation
        mediaPlayer.pause()
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun onStop() {
        // Media player will stop even if the screen is just changing orientation
        mediaPlayer.stop()
    }

}
```

Media player stop and pause is used just for demonstrative purposes.

Note that the architecture in mind is MVVM so passing a weak reference to fragment around is undesirable.

Comment: Can you please share a code snippet of your lifecycle aware component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out lifecycle event functions can receive a `lifecycleOwner` as a parameter. I didn't know this existed, didn't find official docs on it, a colleague of mine told me about this and it works.

Anyway simply check if the `lifecycleOwner` is a `Fragment` or an `Activity` and then call either `activity?.isChangingConfiguration` or `isChangingConfiguration`.

In short, something like this would work:

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
fun onStop(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner) {
    // Cast lifecycleOwner to Fragment or Activity and use isChangingConfiguration
}
```

Comment: Have you been able to do the configuration changing check on `Fragment` as well? I've tried but it seems there's no property to verify that there...

Comment: `Fragment` has a reference to `activity`.

Comment: It does, but in my case it wasn't helping a lot. I needed the configuration changing information in my `ViewModel`. So making the `VM` aware of the `Fragment` even if just inside that callback wasn't really the best idea with respect to MVVM. So my solution was creating a `isConfigurationChanging` field in the `VM` that I would update in `onPause` from the `Fragment`'s `activity` reference, when the Activity is already aware if there is a configuration change happening.

Comment: Research `lifecycle aware components`. This link looks good as well https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles#0. In short, you can use a `LifecycleObserver` to simply observe a `Lifecycle` and avoid making your own callbacks inside the `VM`. Such callbacks defeat the purpose of `MVVM`.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I am already using the lifecycle callbacks in my `VM`. The only difference from your solution is that I am using them without the `LifecycleOwner` parameter. The reason for that is (source: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle#use-cases): "Avoid referencing a View or Activity context in your ViewModel. If the ViewModel outlives the activity (in case of configuration changes), your activity leaks and isn't properly disposed by the garbage collector.". It may not leak from using it as a parameter, but in MVVM, the VM shouldn't be aware of View

Comment: ^ Hence the `isConfigurationChanging` set from the View layer was needed. This way, we make use of the `MVVM` rule that `View` layer is aware of `ViewModel` layer.

Comment: You misread, they mean don't keep it as a field in your class. Simply getting it as a parameter is completely fine. As soon as the function ends, the function scope/stack will be removed, which means you don't keep a reference to any of the parameters you receive unless you store them as a class member.

Comment: Actually some information about lifecycleOwner param is written in doc in source file [Lifecycle.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/lifecycle/lifecycle-common/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle.java?source=post_page---------------------------%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F&autodive=0%2F#70) (Line 70).