# Android How Lifecycle-Aware Components Detect Configuration Change inside ViewModel

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel, android-configchanges

**My `Fragment`:**

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentFirstBinding
    private lateinit var viewModelFactory: FirstViewModelFactory
    private lateinit var viewModel: FirstViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
        viewModelFactory = FirstViewModelFactory(requireActivity().application, this.lifecycle) //<- Lifecycle object
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(FirstViewModel::class.java)

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

**My `ViewModel:`**

```
class FirstViewModel(application: Application, lifecycle: Lifecycle) : AndroidViewModel(application), LifecycleObserver {
    init {
        lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    private fun showOnStopMessage() {
        Log.v("xxx", "onStop called!!")
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    private fun showOnStartMessage() {
        Log.v("xxx", "onStart called!!")
    }
}
```

The above setup works well in **no-configuration-change** environment, `showOnStopMessage()` gets called when app goes to the background, and `showOnStartMessage()` gets called when the app is brought back to the foreground.

The problem is, when **configuration-change** happens (like rotating the screen), those functions are not being called any more.

Why this happens? How to detect and "survive" configuration-change? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Android ViewModel is [specifically designed](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) to persist until the activity is destroyed and to survive configuration changes.

Comment: @Brugui What does it relate to Lifecycle-Aware components?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59411774/7491884) might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, the problem is that your ViewModel is created only once (as it should be) and it only adds the lifecycle of the first fragment as a LifecycleObserver. When you rotate the screen, the same ViewModel is returned and it'll still try to react to the changes of the old Fragment, which won't happen.

I'd suggest not dealing with lifecycle inside the ViewModel at all (remove the related code from the Factory and from the ViewModel). Just call:

```
lifecycle.addObserver(viewModel)
```

right after the ViewModel is obtained, inside onCreateView.

Comment: Wow I see, after configuration change, the `LifecycleOwner` (which is the `Fragment`) gets destroyed and recreated, as well as its `lifecycle` object, but my `ViewModel` is still holding the previous `lifecycle` object, no wonder! Thank you so much!

Comment: Exactly! No problem.